# How to save data temporarily on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to save some images from my server to the iPhone app temporarily.

It is one of my application's purposes to, when the user closes the app, delete the saved images.

Again, when the user starts my application and taps on the corresponding button again, I need to save the data.  I don't know how to start it, I know only we can do this with the help of NSFileManager.

Please can anyone guide me on how to start or write the code.. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Store the files in either the `tmp` or `Library/Caches` folder. In neither case will the files be *automatically* deleted, but they won't be backed up and so don't contribute permanently to the app's storage requirements. If you also want to delete the files on close, do it in `-applicationWillTerminate`.

Comment: some one please xplain it clearly am very new to this platform..don't mind please